# EOF not detected by C on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi

So I was writing a program on my Raspberry Pi Zero to count the frequencies of different word lengths in the input, but the program didn't stop at EOF.

So I tried this to debug:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
    char c;
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

And compiled with this:

```
gcc test.c && ./a.out <input.txt
```

It printed out the input text, but then just kept printing question marks until I hit Ctrl+C. When I copied the program over onto my laptop and ran it there, everything worked fine.

I could just finish on the laptop, but I'm curious. Why can't the Pi detect when the file hit EOF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First couple of facts:

- The symbol `EOF` is a macro that expands to the integer constant `-1`. This integer constant will have the type `int`.
- It's implementation-defined if `char` is signed or unsigned. The same compiler on different platforms might have different `char` implementations.

Now for the long explanation about your problem:

When integer types of different sizes are used in arithmetic expressions (and comparison is considered an arithmetic operator), then both operands of the expression undergoes [*usual arithmetic conversion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions) to get a common type (usually `int`).

For smaller integer types, like for example `char`, that involves [*integer promotion*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to convert it to an `int`. For this promotion the value of the `char` needs to be kept intact, so e.g. `-1` as a `char` will still be `-1` as an `int`.

Because of how negative numbers are represented on most systems, the `char` value of `-1` is (in hexadecimal) `0xff`. For a signed `char`, when `-1` is converted to an `int`, it keeps the value `-1` (which will be represented as `0xffffffff` for a 32-bit `int` type).

The problem comes when `char` is *unsigned*, because then when `getchar` returns `EOF` (the value `-1`) the unsigned `char` value will be equal to `255` (the unsigned decimal representation of `0xff`). And when promoted to an `int` the value will *still* be `255`. And `255 != -1`!

That's why the [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) return type is `int` and not `char`. And one of the reason why *all* character-handling functions are using `int` instead of `char`.

So to solve your problem, you need to change the type of the variable `c` to `int`:

```
int c;
```

Then it will work

Answer (score 2):

`getchar` returns `int` value not `char` value. Since you need some way to recognise in one `getchar` function if you read regular character or if function tells you there is nothing more to read - someone long time ago decided to use `int` so that some value bigger than `char` can be returned to indicate end of file. Change `char` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar's return value` is supposed to be able to return any ASCII (and extended ASCII) character between 0 and 255.

In order to make the distinction between an ascii and EOF, EOF cannot be a value in this interval, so getchar's return type must have more than 8 bits.

```
   int getchar(void);
```

So you should write

```
int c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF) ...
```